# subgroups of inverse image under an epimorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi: G \longrightarrow G_1$ be an epimorphism. Suppose that $H \leq G_1$. Then it follows that $\phi^{-1}(H) \leq G$

Let $K \leq \phi^{-1}(H)$. Can I say that $K = \phi^{-1}(H_1)$ for some $H_1 \leq G_1$?

Comment: $\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$ is contained in the preimage of any subgroup, so you can show that $K=\phi^{-1}(H_1)$ some $H_1\le G_1$ if and only if $K$ contains $\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$. Specifically $K=\phi^{-1}(\phi(K))$.

Answer (score 0):

The preimage of a group homorphism $\phi :G\longrightarrow G_1$ induces a bijection between subgroups of $G $ containing $\mathrm {Ker} (\phi) $ and subgroups of ($G_1$ contained in) $\mathrm {Im} (\phi) $.

This follows at once from induced group isomorphism $G/\mathrm {Ker}(\phi)\cong\mathrm {Im}(\phi) $.